# how to fix failed to load extension with protractortesting?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to run my end to end test but it starts with an error in a messagebox:

```
---------------------------
Error Loading Extension
---------------------------
Failed to load extension from: ...\Temp\scoped_dir9480_28393\internal. Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator.
```

My protractorconfig file contains this:
`chromeDriver:'c:/ptor/protractor/protractor-master/chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0/chromedriver.exe'`

The test works just this error message at the beginning. So how can I avoid this messagebox?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you're not able to install extensions in Google Chrome on your machine?

You could check it in the registry See answer from Mark Collin [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/webdriver/134hkbajh5/unable-to-open-google-chrome-browser-and-execute-a-test-script#20130423jl5iihkvcgzbzwi2t7o3awifam):

Also: why are you providing the path to chromeDriver? I'm always using directConnect in the protractor config (previously `chromeOnly`). like this:

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect : true,
    //More configuration here
}
```